# I can not make a function in a separate thread

Tags: c++

sample code:

```
void check()
{
    sleep(15);
}

int main(int argc, char **argv)
{
    std::thread t(check);
    t.join();

    //......

    return 0;
}
```

The program does not continue to operate until it wakes up...

Comment: you need to describe what you want in order to get a good answer.

Comment: _"The program **does not continue** to operate until **it wakes up**..."_ - what's the problem?  Even people don't get out of bed unless they wake up.  Unless they sleep walk I suppose...

Answer (score 0):

```
t.join();
```

This will *wait* for the thread to complete. Remove the line.

Comment: It's probably better to move `t.join()` aomewhere near to the end of `main()`, rather than simply deleting it.

Comment: if I remove it "t.join();" get error "terminate called without an active exception"

Answer (score 0):

`join` means "wait for the thread to finish, then clean it up".

If you don't want to wait for the thread yet, then don't call `join` yet. Do something else, then join the thread when you need whatever it's doing to complete. Or call `detach`, and let the thread run in the background; although in this case, it will end along with the rest of the program when `main` finishes.